# Change Default Render Output to JPEG with 98% Quality

Tags: rendering, image, file-format

Whenever I save a render to my disk, I typically save it in JPEG format because the vast majority of the time, JPEG saves faster and smaller than the default format, PNG with RGBA color mode.

Because JPEG is a lossy compression codec, I usually set the quality to 98% instead of the default of 90%, since at 98% there is usually little or no loss of quality, and (as a bonus) it can sometimes reduce noise in cycles renders by a tiny bit.

However, each time I save a render, I have to first change the output format to JPEG, and then change the image quality from 90% to 98%.

Is there any way I can set the default image save format to a JPEG with 98% quality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a new project and change the output format to JPEG 98% quality in the render settings panel:

[image]

Then, from the File menu, choose "Save Startup File" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>).  That will make your compression setting the default for all new projects, and for images saved from the UV/Image editor window.

Comment: Doesn't affect existing projects, but that's fine with me, since I can just apply this change to them as I go.  I'll note however, that with .blend files containing multiple scenes, it must be applied to each individual scene.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus The way you can apply this new setting to old projects is by **disabling** the **LoadUI** box when you load an old project, thus forcing blender to use the new setting and ignore the settings saved on the file. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5m27W.png

Comment: @cegaton Aye, I'm aware of that.  However, it would also revert several other settings, which I don't want.

Comment: They really should make that part of the preferences.

Comment: Could this answer be updated for blender 3?